# Inject additional hints into `COMMIT_EDITMSG` during `git-commit`

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks

#### The problem

When I run `git commit` without `-m`, git launches a commit message editor with some hints, something like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   new file:   bar
#
```

I often find myself running `git log --oneline -n 10` before committing, just to see what the commit messages look like so I can write in a similar style. So it would be great if this information is injected into the commit message editor as additional hints. Something like this would be ideal:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   new file:   bar
#
# Last 10 commits:
#   bbbbbbb (HEAD -> master) Another commit
#   aaaaaaa Initial commit
#
```

What is the proper way to do this?

#### What I've tried

Naturally I thought of git hooks, in particular [`prepare-commit-msg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg). This is what I wrote:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

# Show last 10 (max) commits
echo '# Last 10 commits:' >> "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
git log --oneline -n 10 --decorate=short | sed 's/^/#   /' >> "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
echo '#' >> "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
```

This mostly works fine except for one thing - it doesn't work fine. While this info is now injected as hints correctly when running `git commit`, it also has the unintended side effect of breaking commands like `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase`. For example, if I have a commit that looks like this:

```
ccccccc Add baz
```

And I try to `git cherry-pick ccccccc`, it turns into this instead:

```
ddddddd Add baz # Last 10 commits: #   bbbbbbb (HEAD -> master) Another commit #   aaaaaaa Initial commit #
```

As you can see, the hints I inserted are not interpreted correctly without an interactive editor and clobber the commit message instead. Obviously this is not what I want. I did try to investigate whether I can use the script arguments to only inject hints in interactive mode, but it's not obvious how to do that or whether it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is controlled by [--cleanup=$mode](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---cleanupltmodegt) or the configuration variable [commit.cleanup](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitcleanup).

```
git commit --cleanup=strip
# Or
git -c commit.cleanup=strip commit
```

With `strip`, the commentary is removed no matter the commit message is edited or not.

With `default`, the commentary is removed if the commit message is edited, and not removed if it's not edited.

> strip
>
> Strip leading and trailing empty lines, trailing whitespace, commentary and collapse consecutive empty lines.
>
> whitespace
>
> Same as strip except #commentary is not removed.
>
> default
>
> Same as strip if the message is to be edited. Otherwise whitespace.

So, I think you can use `git config --global commit.cleanup strip`.

Comment: Good catch. I guess an alternative suggestion could be: from the prepare-commit-msg hook, detect if the repo is in a "regular" state or if it is in the middle of a rebase or cherry-pick

Comment: @LeGEC I had the same idea. I think we can test the temporary file like `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` and `REBASE_HEAD` to see if it's a cherry-pick or rebase. But in fact, the OP's problem also occurs during `git commit -m "message"`. I have no idea how to find it out if it's interactive or not interactive.

Comment: The documentation tells you that the second argument to the hook being `message` indicates that `-m` or `-F` were used (similarly, `commit` for `-c`). You can base your decision on that.